# how to filter () a pairRDD according to two conditions

Tags: apache-spark, keyvaluepair

how can i filter my pair RDD if i have 2 conditions for filter it , one to test the key and the other one to test the value (wanna the portion of code) bcz i used this portion and it didnt work saddly

```
JavaPairRDD filtering = pairRDD1.filter((x,y) -> (x._1.equals(y._1))&&(x._2.equals(y._2)))));
```

Comment: What didn't work? What types are you dealing with? We need more detail about what you're trying to do to help.

Comment: i have a  pairRDD which may contain different values for the same key, or the same tuple is repeated, i want to keep only tuples which are repeated

Comment: eg.if my rdd contains{(1,white),(1,black),(2,red),(2,red)} so what iwant to keep is only {(2,red),(2,red)}

Comment: Your `RDD` is a sequence of tuples?

Comment: well it should contain only tuples like those (and every key is repeated) somtimes with same value some times not

Answer (score 0):

You can't use regular filter for this, because that checks one item at a time. You have to compare multiple items to each other, and check which one to keep. Here's an example which only keeps items which are repeated:

```
val items = List(1, 2, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13, 15, 16, 16, 19, 20)
val rdd = sc.parallelize(items)
// now create an RDD with all possible combinations of pairs
val mapped = rdd.map { case (x) => (x, 1)}
val reduced = mapped.reduceByKey{ case (x, y) => x + y }
val filtered = reduced.filter { case (item, count) => count > 1 }
// Now print out the results:
filtered.collect().foreach { case (item, count) =>
   println(s"Keeping $item because it occurred $count times.")}
```

It's probably not the most performant code for this, but it should give you an idea for the approach.

Comment: but i can't guess what are items which can appear